# Gatbsy Programatically create pages with specified routes

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby as a static site generator to programatically generate content using markdown.

With my file structure as follows:

```
src/
├─ content/
│  ├─ music/
│  │  ├─ first
│  │  ├─ second
│  ├─ software/
│  │  ├─ first
│  │  ├─ second
│  ├─ writing/
```

All of these files have slugs defined in their frontmatter.

I would like to dynamically generate pages at:
`website.com/software/first`

or

`website.com/music/second`

and so forth

I've tried using Gatbsy's createFilePath api to create the node, as follows

in gatsby-node.js

```js
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: "content" })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}
```

And using this path i then create the page

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

However, pages are not being created with the folder that is containing them, as part of the route. For example it is only being created at: `website.com/first`

Does anyone know how I can incorporate this into the path? I suspect by changing `basePath` which I have tried to no avail.